# Run Time Error 3464 Data type misatch

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

This code Whenever I am entering is giving:

> The Data mismatch error 3464

I was trying to practice your video "Create Login From Access Part 1"

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  If IsNull(Me.txtLoginId) Then
      MsgBox "Please enter LoginID", vbInformation, "LoginID Required"
      Me.txtLoginId.SetFocus
   ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
     MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
     Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
   Else
     'process the job
     If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin ='" & Me.txtLoginId.Value & "'"))) Or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("password", "tblUser", "Password ='" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
       MsgBox "Incorrect LoginId or Password"
     Else
       MsgBox "LoginID and Password correct"
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong, I know you copied it from the video but it's not done right and I think author had modified later on. For example this is not testing if user id matches the password, it just tests if userid or password match to any values. So you could potentially have multiple users that have same passwords and it would pass validation. When you get the data type mismatch it would indicate that your table is not setup right, looking at the quotes here both userid and password should be text..are they?

What you want is something like this;
If (IsNull(DLookup("[UserLogin]", "tblUser", "[Userlogin] ='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'  And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then

But instead of using DLookup I would use eLookup.. much faster and more flexible. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html